# Place tsconfig.json to root of project

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have a webpack environment for Angular 2 development.

How can I change the directory for the tsconfig.json file. I want to move it to root of project. I know it has to be amended here. But I do not understand how can I get rid of path.resolve

```js
options: { configFileName: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json') }
```

The whole file webpack.config.js is here

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin'); 
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts'
      },
   output:{
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),   
       publicPath: '/',
       filename: '[name].[hash].js'
   },
   devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
   resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
   module:{
       rules:[   //загрузчик для ts
           {
               test: /\.ts$/, 
               use: [
                {
                    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    options: { configFileName: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json') }
                  } ,
                   'angular2-template-loader'
               ]
            }, {
              test: /\.html$/,
              loader: 'html-loader'
            },{
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
          },{
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app'),
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: "style-loader", use: "css-loader"})
          },{
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app'),
            loader: 'raw-loader'
          }
       ]
   },
   plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /angular(\\|\/)core/,
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 
      {} 
    ),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['app', 'polyfills']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new UglifyJSPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      htmlLoader: {
        minimize: false
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: `__dirname` should point to the folder where the webpack process is being imported (`require()`).  Where is `webpack.config.js` located relative to the root?  If it is in `/webpack`, then you can change your path to `../'tsconfig.json'`, for example.  I didn't put this as an answer because I haven't tested it in a while.

Comment: I have webpack.config.js located in the root of the app. So is tsconfig.json

Comment: options: { configFileName: 'tsconfig.json' } 
will this work if these files are in the root folder?